# Select for Opened, Closed and Backlog

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by

I have the following table:

```
+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| status      | open_time           | close_time          |
+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|      closed | 01-11-2014 19:32:44 | 01-11-2014 20:32:44 |
|        open | 01-12-2014 22:33:49 | 02-12-2014 22:33:49 |
|        open | 01-23-2014 22:08:24 | 03-23-2014 22:08:24 |
|      closed | 02-01-2014 22:33:57 | 03-01-2014 22:33:57 |
|        open | 02-01-2013 22:37:34 | 02-01-2013 23:37:34 |
|      closed | 04-20-2013 15:23:00 | 05-20-2013 15:23:00 |
|        open | 04-20-2013 12:21:49 | 05-20-2013 12:21:49 |
|      closed | 04-25-2013 11:22:00 | 06-25-2013 11:22:00 |
|      closed | 05-20-2013 14:23:49 | 10-20-2013 14:23:49 |
|      closed | 04-20-2013 16:33:49 | 04-25-2013 16:33:49 |
+-------------+---------------------+---------------------*
```

I would like to show this result:

```
+-------------+---------------+--------------+---------+
| Year | Month | Opened Cases | Closed Cases | Backlog |
+-------------+---------------+--------------+---------+
| 2014 |     4 |           10 |            5 |      62 | (57 + 5)
| 2014 |     3 |            9 |            7 |      57 | (52 + 2)    
| 2014 |     2 |           15 |           20 |      52 | (57 - 5)
| 2014 |     1 |           12 |            1 |      57 | (46 + 11)
| 2013 |    12 |           10 |            9 |      46 | (45 + 1)
| 2013 |    11 |           50 |            5 |      45 | (45)
+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------+
```

Actually I am facing 2 situations:

- Situation #1: I am not able to get the right value for the Closed Cases. Tried to work with clauses in where but no luck.
- Situation #2: After retrive the Closed Cases, I should do the (Opened - Closed) and accumulate it over the months, so this will be the backlog.

## For the Situation #1:

If I do the following select:

```
SELECT
  YEAR(open_time) AS Ano,
  MONTH(open_time) AS Mes,
  sum(CASE WHEN DATEPART(YYYY, open_time)= 2013 AND DATEPART(MM, open_time)= 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Abertos,
  sum(CASE WHEN DATEPART(YYYY, close_time)= 2013 AND DATEPART(MM, close_time)= 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Fechados
FROM
  TABLE
WHERE
  GROUPDESC= 'SUPPORT'
GROUP BY
  MONTH(open_time),
  YEAR(open_time)
ORDER BY
  Ano DESC,
  Mes DESC
```

I get (this is the right value for closed cases):

```
+-------------+---------------+--------------+
| Year | Month | Opened Cases | Closed Cases |
+-------------+---------------+--------------+
| 2014 |     4 |            0 |            0 |
| 2014 |     3 |            0 |            0 |
| 2014 |     2 |            0 |            0 |
| 2014 |     1 |            0 |            0 |
| 2013 |    12 |            0 |            0 |
| 2013 |    11 |           50 |            5 |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

But if I do:

```
SELECT
  YEAR(open_time) AS Ano,
  MONTH(open_time) AS Mes,
  sum(CASE WHEN DATEPART(YYYY, open_time)= YEAR(open_time) AND DATEPART(MM, open_time)= MONTH(open_time) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Abertos,
  sum(CASE WHEN DATEPART(YYYY, close_time)= YEAR(close_time) AND DATEPART(MM, close_time)= YEAR(close_time) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Fechados
FROM
  TABLE
WHERE
  GROUPDESC= 'SUPPORT'
GROUP BY
  MONTH(open_time),
  YEAR(open_time)
ORDER BY
  Ano DESC,
  Mes DESC
```

I get:

```
+-------------+---------------+--------------+
| Year | Month | Opened Cases | Closed Cases |
+-------------+---------------+--------------+
| 2014 |     4 |            0 |            0 |
| 2014 |     3 |            0 |            0 |
| 2014 |     2 |            0 |            0 |
| 2014 |     1 |            0 |            0 |
| 2013 |    12 |            0 |            0 |
| 2013 |    11 |           50 |           50 |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: The backlog column for the desired results table, for row 2014.3 shows 57.  It should be 54 = 52 + 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to approach the problem: select all opening counts per month and all closing counts per month. Then full outer join them. The cumulation is a so-called running total, which you get with SUM OVER.

```
select
  coalesce(opened.ano, closed.ano) as ano,
  coalesce(opened.mes, closed.mes) as mes,
  coalesce(opened.cnt, 0) as opened_cases,
  coalesce(closed.cnt, 0) as closed_cases,
  sum(coalesce(opened.cnt, 0) - coalesce(closed.cnt, 0)) over (order by coalesce(opened.ano, closed.ano), coalesce(opened.mes, closed.mes)) as backlog
from
(
  select 
    year(open_time) as ano, 
    month(open_time) as mes,
    count(*) as cnt
  from probsummarym1
  where groupdesc = 'SUPPORT'
  group by year(open_time), month(open_time)
) opened
full outer join
(
  select 
    year(close_time) as ano, 
    month(close_time) as mes,
    count(*) as cnt
  from probsummarym1
  where groupdesc = 'SUPPORT'
  and status = 'closed'
  group by year(close_time), month(close_time)
) closed
  on opened.ano = closed.ano and opened.mes = closed.mes
order by coalesce(opened.ano, closed.ano) desc, coalesce(opened.mes, closed.mes) desc;
```

Here is the SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/68dcf/7.

Another way would be to glue the opening events with the closing events with UNION ALL and then count:

```
select 
  ano,
  mes,
  opened_cases,
  closed_cases,
  sum(opened_cases - closed_cases) over (order by ano, mes) as backlog
from
(
  select 
    year(fecha) as ano,
    month(fecha) as mes,
    sum(case when evento = 'opened' then 1 else 0 end) as opened_cases,
    sum(case when evento = 'closed' then 1 else 0 end) as closed_cases
  from
  (
    select 'opened' as evento, open_time as fecha
    from probsummarym1
    where groupdesc = 'SUPPORT'
    union all
    select 'closed' as evento, close_time as fecha
    from probsummarym1
    where groupdesc = 'SUPPORT'
    and status = 'closed'
  ) x 
  group by year(fecha), month(fecha)
) y
order by ano desc, mes desc;
```

And here is the second SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/68dcf/18.

EDIT: No SUM OVER? That's too bad. So you will have to subselect the count. That is slow, because the table must be scanned again for every single month.

For every month we must find all start dates until then and all end dates till then. As an end can never occur before start, we can select all records where the start date matches and count these. Within these records we will also find all potential end dates. We count these (with sum and case), subtract, and we're done.

So you would have to replace the `SUM() OVER as backlog` part thus:

```
  (
    select
      count(*)
      -
      sum
      (
        case 
          when eventsuntil.status = 'closed' 
          and year(eventsuntil.close_time) * 100 + month(eventsuntil.close_time) >= 
              y.ano * 100 + y.mes 
        then 1 else 0
        end
      )    
    from probsummarym1 eventsuntil
    where eventsuntil.groupdesc = 'SUPPORT'
    and year(eventsuntil.open_time) * 100 + month(eventsuntil.open_time) >= 
        y.ano * 100 + y.mes
  ) as backlog
```

However, SQL Server, even in version 2012, is not capable of executing this, which I consider a dbms flaw. y.ano and y.mes (or coalesce(opened.ano, closed.ano) and coalesce(opened.mes, closed.mes) for the first statement) should be considered constants for the inner query, because the evaluation is done per outer record, i.e. month, but they are not. I don't know how to overcome this problem. Maybe some expert on SQL Server can help you here.

Here are the two fiddles that result in syntax errors: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/68dcf/32 and http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/68dcf/31. Sorry I cannot help you here any further.

Comment: first thanks for your time. Both example are exactly what I need, and runs nice in the fiddle, but in my scenario I got an error I think it is because the sql-server version. Mine is 10.50.2500 (2008 I think). In the first example all runs ok besides the line: `sum(coalesce(opened.cnt, 0) - coalesce(closed.cnt, 0)) over (order by coalesce(opened.ano, closed.ano), coalesce(opened.mes, closed.mes)) as backlog`.

Comment: Okay, I've edited my answer. However, the dbms even has problems with that old-style solution, so you need expert advice on SQL Server here, which I am not able to give. Sorry and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
;with CTE as (
    SELECT
        row_number() over (partition by groupdesc order by YEAR(open_time), MONTH(open_time)) "Date_Order",
        YEAR(open_time) "Year",
        MONTH(open_time) "Month",
        SUM(CASE status WHEN 'open' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "open_count",
        SUM(CASE status WHEN 'closed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "closed_count",
        SUM(CASE status WHEN 'open' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE status WHEN 'closed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "monthly_change"
    FROM PROBSUMMARYM1
    WHERE groupdesc = 'SUPPORT'
    GROUP BY groupdesc,
        YEAR(open_time),
        MONTH(open_time)
)
select c1.Date_Order,
    c1.Year,
    c1.Month,
    c1.open_count,
    c1.closed_count,
    sum(c2.monthly_change) "Backlog"
from CTE c1
join CTE c2
    on c2.Date_Order <= c1.Date_Order
group by c1.Date_Order,
    c1.Year,
    c1.Month,
    c1.open_count,
    c1.closed_count
order by c1.Year desc,
    c1.Month desc;
```

The `partition by groupdesc` and then grouping by `groupdesc` is not strictly necessary, but it demonstrates how you'd use `row_number()` to simultaneously run one query to do the same thing for multiple `groupdesc`.

You may be able to get away with just using `SUM() OVER()`, but I'm not that experienced with the `OVER()` clause.  See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx , specifically example C.

Comment: the `open_count` column shows only 0 for all lines. See: http://oi60.tinypic.com/2v3ork5.jpg

Comment: Is it possible to use the dates to SUM instead of the status?

Comment: Well, what's actually stored in `status`?  Is it truly `'open'` or is it some other value?  Is there whitespace padding that should be trimmed (`'  open'`)?  Are you using case-sensitive collation?

Comment: The reason is that I have others status. Sorry, I shouldn't have show that column in the example, that is why I used the date in the example, sorry.

Comment: "Is it possible to use the dates to SUM instead of the status?"  Maybe.  That significantly complicates the logic.  I'm not sure how I'd do that with aggregated data like this.  I'd probably create a subquery that just calculates the opened tickets and a query that just calculates the closed tickets.  Then join those and use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.  Then in a third query do the backlog calculation.