# Select and Count with Null values

Tags: select, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following select:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE (opened.ano, closed.ano) AS ano,
    COALESCE (opened.mes, closed.mes) AS mes,
    COALESCE (opened.cnt, 0) AS opened_cases,
    COALESCE (closed.cnt, 0) AS closed_cases
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            YEAR (OPEN_DATE) AS ano,
            MONTH (OPEN_DATE) AS mes,
            COUNT (*) AS cnt
        FROM
            TABLE1,
            TABLE2
        WHERE
            TABLE1.USERNAME = TABLE2.USERNAME
        AND TABLE2.GROUP = 'SUPPORT'
        GROUP BY
            YEAR (OPEN_DATE),
            MONTH (OPEN_DATE)
    ) opened
FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
        YEAR (CLOSE_DATE) AS ano,
        MONTH (CLOSE_DATE) AS mes,
        COUNT (*) AS cnt
    FROM
        TABLE1,
        TABLE2
    WHERE
        TABLE1.USERNAME = TABLE2.USERNAME
    AND TABLE2.GROUP = 'SUPPORT'
    GROUP BY
        YEAR (CLOSE_DATE),
        MONTH (CLOSE_DATE)
) closed ON opened.ano = closed.ano
AND opened.mes = closed.mes
ORDER BY
    COALESCE (opened.ano, closed.ano) ASC,
    COALESCE (opened.mes, closed.mes) ASC;
```

The result is:

[image]

The situation:

The first line with null values are lost because there is no null condition in the select.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure they should be added to that line? Those are rows with no `CLOSE_DATE` but, importantly, they've probably already been counted for the appropriate period that their `OPEN_DATE` refers to. I'd have thought adding them in would result in double-counting them.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, you are right. Those rows are being counted and 3 of 4 cases are opened in april and one in may and all four still opened. So is it possible to change the select to:

If the closed_date is null then get the year and month from the opened_date and add 1.

Thanks.

Comment: I would have thought that the correct fix for your data would simply to be an extra filter for the `closed` query, where the `CLOSE_DATE` isn't null. You're still talking about adding random numbers elsewhere that still feels wrong.

Comment: Sorry @Damien_The_Unbeliever, you still right. A filter for the null values in the select should fix it. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
  coalesce(opened.ano, closed.ano) as ano,
  coalesce(opened.mes, closed.mes) as mes,
  coalesce(opened.cnt, 0) as opened_cases,
  coalesce(closed.cnt, 0) as closed_cases
from
(
  select 
    year(open_time) as ano, 
    month(open_time) as mes,
    count(*) as cnt
  from table1
  where groupdesc = 'SUPPORT'
  group by year(open_time), month(open_time)
) opened
full outer join
(
  select 
    year(close_time) as ano, 
    month(close_time) as mes,
    count(*) as cnt
  from table1
  where groupdesc = 'SUPPORT'
  group by year(close_time), month(close_time)
) closed
  on opened.ano = closed.ano and opened.mes = closed.mes
where closed.mes is not null
order by coalesce(opened.ano, closed.ano) desc, coalesce(opened.mes, closed.mes)    desc;
```

This is your SQL with an added WHERE clause.
Your comments seem to show that what you are looking for IS contained in this results set.
There are 10 Opened_cases and 8 closed_cases.

Comment: Hi, you wanto me to change the `ON` clause? I changed to this `ON 
   (opened.ano = closed.ano) or (opened.ano is null and closed.ano is null)
AND (opened.mes = closed.mes) or (opened.mes is null and closed.mes is null)` but doen't work.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to accomplish.  When you say, "The first line with null values are lost because there is no null condition in the select."  

This row is not lost as it IS in the result set.

Is it because you have a data row that has a OPEN_DATE with a NULL CLOSE_DATE, that you are desiring to see that show in the results?

Your problem is not clear.

Also knowing which table has the OPEN_DATE and CLOSE_DATE will help.  Perhaps you can comment with the table structure for Table1 and Table2.

Comment: One example: If a ticket has no close_date, thus a null value, it means it is open, so it should count as open. This is what the select isn't doing.

Comment: This thread help me a lot in the start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23012547/select-for-opened-closed-and-backlog. There are some sqlfiddle.

Comment: This is what is happening: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3bf0ac/1. The 2 cases should belongs to the open cases based in the year and month from the open_time. 1 for 2014/01 and other for 2013/02

Comment: Thanks for your time RosSQL, your answer works nicely!

Answer (score 1):

So in your fiddler example there should be 10 opened cases and 8 closed?

Is so, Then try this: (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3bf0ac/9)

```
;
with opened AS (
  select 
    year(open_time) as ano, 
    month(open_time) as mes,
    count(*) as cnt
  from table1
  where groupdesc = 'SUPPORT'
  group by year(open_time), month(open_time)
  ),
closed AS (
  select 
    year(close_time) as ano, 
    month(close_time) as mes,
    count(*) as cnt
  from table1
  where groupdesc = 'SUPPORT'
  group by year(close_time), month(close_time)
)
SELECT 
    COALESCE (opened.ano, closed.ano) AS ano,
    COALESCE (opened.mes, closed.mes) AS mes,
    COALESCE (opened.cnt, 0) AS opened_cases,
    COALESCE (closed.cnt, 0) AS closed_cases
FROM opened
FULL OUTER JOIN closed on opened.ano = closed.ano and opened.mes = closed.mes
WHERE COALESCE (opened.ano, closed.ano) IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY coalesce(opened.ano, closed.ano) desc, coalesce(opened.mes, closed.mes) desc;
```